# PHPExcel str_replace

Tags: hyperlink, phpexcel, str-replace

i want to convert my excel hyperlink's path to open links with PHPExcel.

```
$links = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHyperlinkCollection();
```

This method will return an array of hyperlink objects, indexed by cell address; and you could then use array_filter() with an appropriate callback and the ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY flag set to extract those within a specific range.

my var_dump($links); output :

[image]

But i dont know how to loop the array of objects with array_filter() function..

I try :

```
 $test = str_replace($links, "file", "mnt");
 var_dump($test);
```

and i got the error above.. Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection is an array of objects, indexed by cell address; and the `PHPExcel_Cell_Hyperlink` object has a set of documented methods for accessing and setting its data:

```
foreach($links as $cellAddress => $link) {
    // get the URL from the PHPExcel_Cell_Hyperlink object
    $url = $link->getUrl();
    // change the URL however you want here
    $url = str_replace($url, "file", "mnt");
    // Set the new value for the link
    $link->setUrl($url);
}
```

If you want to modify just those URLs for cells in column `N`, then you can wrap them in an `if` test:

```
foreach($links as $cellAddress => $link) {
    // Test for column N
    sscanf($cellAddress, '%[A-Z]%d', $column, $row);
    if ($column == 'N') {
        // get the URL from the PHPExcel_Cell_Hyperlink object
        $url = $link->getUrl();
        // change the URL however you want here
        $url = str_replace($url, "file", "mnt");
        // Set the new value for the link
        $link->setUrl($url);
    }
}
```